# how to write cloud endpoints unittests with authentication?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm writing unittests (using [webtest](https://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) for a Cloud Endpoints API written in python. One of these methods requires authentication. I've set USER_ID, USER_EMAIL and USER_IS_ADMIN with testbed.setup_env(), but that doesn't seem to work. What's the best way to mock authentication for endpoints unittests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the correct answer is to mock out endpoints.get_current_user() and possibly oauth.is_current_user_admin()!